# Ordering text file entries by letter

Tags: php

I am new to PHP so I'm sorry if anything I ask isn't clear.

My goal is to take information from a simple HTML form that asks for users to fill out three text boxes, select if they are user 1 or user 2, and upload a file.  I then have to store the information in a text file and display that information in the browser directly below the HTML form.  The information must be ordered alphabetically by the first letter of whatever is entered in the first text box.  Each entry must be on its own line.

For example:

Let's say Person 1 enters: Sally Mae Johnson User 1 Flowers.jpg
Person 2 comes along later and enters: George Michael Johnson User 2 books.jpg

Right now it displays in the order entered like this:
Sally Mae Johnson User 1 Flowers.jpg
George Michael Johnson User 2 books.jpg

I need it to display in alphabetical order by the first letter of the first name like this:
George Michael Johnson user 2 books.jpg
Sally Mae Johnson User 1 Flowers.jpg

Here's my code:

```
$fone = @$_POST["one"];
$ftwo = @$_POST["two"];
$fthree = @$_POST["three"];
$fselect = @$_POST["select"];

if ($_FILES)
{
    $name = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
    (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], "uploads/$name"));
}


//write to the file

$values = "$fone\t";
$values .= "$ftwo\t";
$values .= "$fthree\t";
$values .= "$fselect\t"; 
$values .= "<img src='uploads/$name' /><br />";


//open and write to the file

$fp = @fopen("store.txt", "a") or die("Couldn't open the file!");
$numBytes = @fwrite($fp, $values) or die ("Couldn't write values to file!");


@fclose($fp);


?>
<form action="test_it.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
Box 1: <input type="text" name="one" size="15" /> 
Box 2: <input type="text" name="two" size="15" />
Box 3: <input type="text" name="three" size="15" />
Select One: <select name="select"><option value="empty">Please Select</option><option value="user1">User 1</option>
<option value="user2">User 2</option>
<p>Upload a File:</p>
<p><input type="file" name="upload" />
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="submitted" />
</p>
</form>
<?php

print "<P>Here are the users:<br />";
$file = "store.txt";

if (file_exists($file))
{
    $file1 = fopen("store.txt" , "r");
        while (!feof($file1))
        {
            $display = fgets($file1, filesize("store.txt"));
            echo $display . "
            ";
            }
            fclose($file1);
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<P>Error occured! Please try again!</p>";
            }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an array first.

```
$valuesArray = array();
$valuesArray[] = $fone;
    ... etc.
```

Then,

```
$valuesArray = sort($valuesArray);
```

Finally, prepare the text:

```
$values = $valuesArray[0] . "\t";
    ... etc.
```

And write to the file.

```
$numBytes = @fwrite($fp, $values) or die ("Couldn't write values to file!");
```

Comment: Won't this alphabetize the words in each entry? I need to have each total entry alphabetized.  For example say one person enters: sally1, sally2, sally3, then selects user 1 and uploads a picture called books. jpg. Then another person comes along later and enters george1 george2 george3 user2 flowers.jpg, I need it to display on the first line: george1 george2 george3 user2 flowers.jpg and then on the next line: sally1, sally2, sally3, user1 books.jpg.  Does this make sense? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You seem to have left some details out of your question.  In your question, all inputs come from a single `$_POST` request, and it's not possible for both the first person *and* the second person to provide their data in the same `$_POST`.  I imagine that in your real code, you are making a database call.  The problem may revolve around how you are integrating the database call/s with your code.  Can you please amend your question and include the relevant database portion of the code?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you're talking about.  I entered the code exactly as I have it.  Each new person is able to enter their information, it just displays the information in the order entered and not alphabetical like I need it.  I'm really sorry if I'm annoying you but I'm totally clueless when it comes to this stuff.

Comment: Please provide examples of (a) information entered, and by whom it is entered; (b) desired output as seen by each person, and (c) actual output as seen by each person.  Also, if you could confirm that each person is sitting at a different computer (and thereby sending a different request). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fone = @$_POST["one"];
$ftwo = @$_POST["two"];
$fthree = @$_POST["three"];
$fselect = @$_POST["select"];

if ($_FILES)
{
    $name = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
    (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], "uploads/$name"));
}


// sort the entries 
$entries = array($fone, $ftwo, $fthree, $fselect);
sort($entries);

$values = implode("\t", $entries)."\t";
$values .= "<img src='uploads/$name' /><br />";


//open and write to the file

$fp = @fopen("store.txt", "a") or die("Couldn't open the file!");
$numBytes = @fwrite($fp, $values) or die ("Couldn't write values to file!");


@fclose($fp);
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not seem to work.  It simply lists the entries in the order they were entered.  Do you know why this is?  I do appreciate the help though, thank you!